# BLE Device Response in Android: Byte Array to right Float Value in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, bytebuffer

After Reading from a Gatt Characteristic i have a Problem getting the right Float Value from Result (part).
The Result for Measurement is a **4 byte** value (result1-4), represented as **single-precision0
floating point number** (IEEE 754-2008)

This is my Function:

```
 private fun getMeasurementData(data: ByteArray?, results: Int?) {

    mDebugInfo!!.append("Read Measurements!\n")

    if (data != null && results != null && results > 0) {

        var r = results
        var i = 1

        while (r > 0) {
            var resultId1 = data[i]
            var resultId2 = data[i + 1]
            var measureType = data[i + 2]
            var measureStatus = data[i + 3]
            var datetime1 = data[i + 4]
            var datetime2 = data[i + 5]
            var datetime3 = data[i + 6]
            var datetime4 = data[i + 7]
            var result1 = data[i + 8]
            var result2 = data[i + 9]
            var result3 = data[i + 10]
            var result4 = data[i + 11]

            val bytes = byteArrayOf(result1, result2, result3, result4)
            val buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes, 0, 4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
            val float = buffer.getFloat()

            mDebugInfo!!.append(resultId1.toString() + " | " + resultId2.toString() + " | " + measureType.toString() + " | " + measureStatus.toString() + " | " + datetime1.toString() + " | " + datetime2.toString() + " | " + datetime3.toString() + " | " + datetime4.toString() + " | " + result1.toString() + " | " + result2.toString() + " | " + result3.toString() + " | " + result4.toString() + float +"\n")

            i = i + 16

            r--
        }
    }
}
```

The Output (mDebugInfo) from Byte.toString of result 1-4 & val float is:

| result1 | result2 | result3 | result4 | float from ByteBuffer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 96 | -14 | -13 | -14 | 647.5922785 |

The right Value for Measurement is **7.59** - this Value is "included" in the float Result: 64**7.59** 22785

How do I get this value only?

Comment: I would check via `buf.array()` and print the array content if the buffer really contains what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This Solution works for me:

```
var resultBytes =  byteArrayOf(result4, result3, result2, result1)

private fun getMeasurementValue(ba: ByteArray): String {
    var resultHex = ba.toHexString()
    var iRes = resultHex.toLong(16)
    var fRes = java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat(iRes.toInt()) // This is the FLOAT Value (fRes)

    return String.format("%.2f", fRes)
}
```